# how to execute Sql Raw Query in Microsoft Entity Model Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, search

I'm using Microsoft Entity model framework to access my database. I get an issue while i use this execute query command for executing Sql raw query. Let me know how could i resolve it.

```
svdc.CreateQuery<VideoMasterTable>(
    "select * from videomastertable WHERE FREETEXT(*, '"+keyword+"')"
    ).ToList();
```

Thanks in Advance,

Kanal

Comment: Please don't create your sql commands via string concatenation. That will lead to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Use the Parameterized interface to pass any params.

Answer (score 4):

`CreateQuery` takes ESQL, not T-SQL. In EF 4 (only), you can use `ExecuteStoreQuery` instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your update. But i tried with Executestorequery, But i could not find the solution. Please can i know how could i use this query or a code sample.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx

Answer (score 2):

With CreateQuery method you are creating ObjectQuery wich will be translated to entity sql (ESQL). Entity SQL is not T-SQL. It has different syntax and uses entity operations. Entity Framework doesn't have methods for Full Text Search currently. You can create such methods or use stored procedures and call them using Entity Framework. To create your methods try [this article](http://manfred-ramoser.blogspot.com/2009/09/full-text-search-for-entity-framework.html). For using stored procedures with EF check [this article](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/willemm/archive/2007/09/11/Using-stored-procedures-with-ADO.NET-entity-framework.aspx).